# Is there a way to come up with a generalized Taylor Series for something like $x^2\sin {x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

This is my first time posting and using MathJax but I'll try my best.

So I'm aware that you can use the general TS formula for $\sin x$ to come up with a formula for $\sin x^2$.
Ex: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin x^2 = (-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+2}}{(2n + 1)!}$$
I did this by simply pluging in $x^2$ for $x$

The only problem is that I simply don't know what to do if the $\sin x$ is being multiplied by something. I truthfully don't even really know where to start and I can't really find a solution anywhere. This type of question was asked many times on my practice exam and I'm not sure how to solve it except by using the general TS formula and using the product rule a bunch of times which would take forever.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may literally multiply $x^2$ to each term of the series for $\sin(x^2)$. This essentially follows from the distributivity: $c(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots) = ca_1 + ca_2 + \cdots$.

Comment: Does this mean this statement: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^2\sin x^2 = ((-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+2}}{(2n + 1)!})*x^2$$ would be true?

Comment: I mean $$x^2\sin(x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^2\cdot\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{4n+2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{4n+4}.$$

Comment: so yes.... thanks